# How to declare SKSpriteNode globally in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to switch from Objective-C to Swift, but I can't understand how to declare SKSpriteNode as property. I need this in order to access it from every function.
In objective C it is:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *selectedNode;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In swift, you would have something like

```
class YourClass: UIViewController
{
    var selectedNode: SKSpriteNode
}
```

Depending on when you instanciate SKSpriteNode, you would have a `!` right after the `SKSpriteNode`.

Also, this variable will be accessible outside of your class. Which means you can do something like

```
var myObject = YourClass()
myObject.selectedNode = ...
```

If you want to make it private, you can do this :

```
private var selectedNode: SKSpriteNode
```

Comment: i have no idea why i can't access the variable var sprite: SKSpriteNode       if self.sprite != nil